# CIVICRM Upgrade in Joomla Environment - CRM updates but database aborts

Tags: upgrade, joomla, database

I have a Joomla 3.11 environment running PHP 7.3 and CIVICRM 5.57.  We have followed the steps to upgrade CIVICRM to 5.60/5.61 in Joomla.  The CRM updates fine but it abends when trying to update the database.  I have posted a screenshot of the results below.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the solution in this question: [DB update failure after update 5.60](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/44802/db-update-failure-after-update-5-60/44810#comment52821_44810)

**SOLUTION:**

After restoring the CiviCRM database from the backup, do the following:

Remove all records from civicrm_job_log table by command:

```
DELETE FROM civicrm_job_log;
```

Re-run the update process from the CiviCRM main window, and it will finish successfully.

Comment: That works but removes all your scheduled job logs.  If you want to keep them, see other solutions here: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/44762/225